# AngularJS Server session & authentication with nodeJS backend server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, authentication, cookies

I have a front-end angularJS server that is getting data from a back-end nodeJS server from MySQL DB via middleware.
I created a front-end simple login form that needs to send data for authentication to the back-end server (checks if user exists in the db). 
The back-end server returns user details in the case that the user is found in the DB or prints error login message or redirect to signup screen.

I'm looking for a guide or example on how to create a correct authentication system with sessions and cookies between the two servers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose use a token authentication or use cookies.

Take a look at this,it is a good guide  :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543